# QGIS Virtual Layers from DB query load as 'missing' when opening project file

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer, loading

I'm using QGIS 3.16 and I have a layer from a database query that loads as a table, `'Data_vFoodLocations'`. I then created a bunch of Virtual Layers with queries like the one below:

```sql
select FieldX, FieldY, MakePoint(map_lon, map_lat, 4326) 
from Data_vFoodLocations
```

Whenever I load the project, those Virtual Layers all show up as `'Missing'` and broken.

If I open them with 'Edit virtual layer' and re-add them with no changes, they work fine. It's just annoying to do every time I open the project.

I assume(?) it's something along the lines of the DB query loading after the virtual layers? Is there anything I can do to my project file to fix this?